# Getting Excel fill colors using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI 3.17 to read an Excel 2013 workbook.  The workbook is created and edited by users directly in Excel.  I then run a Java 8 program that uses POI to read and process the workbook.

Some cells are color-coded and so I need to obtain the fill color.  In many cases this works fine, but there are a set of grey/silver colors where it does not work and I'm unsure as to why.

As an example, the Excel cells look like this:

[image: Excel sample]

My code for obtaining the fill color is:

```
private String getFillColor(XSSFCell cell) {
    String fColorString = "None";
    if (cell != null) {
        XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
        
        short sColorFore = cellStyle.getFillForegroundColor();
        short sColorBack = cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor();
        XSSFColor xColorFore =  cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor();
        XSSFColor xColorBack =  cellStyle.getFillBackgroundColorColor();

        String s = "";
        s += " indexFore=" + sColorFore;
        s += " indexBack=" + sColorBack;
        s += " colorFore=" + ((xColorFore == null) ? "Null" : xColorFore.getARGBHex());
        s += " colorBack=" + ((xColorBack == null) ? "Null" : xColorBack.getARGBHex());
        System.out.println("Cell=" + cell.getAddress() + " " + cell.getStringCellValue() + s);
        
        if (xColorFore != null) {
            fColorString = xColorFore.getARGBHex();
        }8
    }
    return fColorString;
}
```

The results of this when called for each of the example Excel cells above are:

> Cell=BBH52 Pink indexFore=0 indexBack=64 colorFore=FFF79646 colorBack=null
>
> Cell=BBH53 No fill indexFore=64 indexBack=64 colorFore=Null colorBack=Null
>
> Cell=BBH54 Grey 1 indexFore=0 indexBack=64 colorFore=FFFFFFFF colorBack=null
>
> Cell=BBH55 Grey 2 indexFore=0 indexBack=64 colorFore=FFFFFFFF colorBack=null
>
> Cell=BBH56 Grey 3 indexFore=0 indexBack=64 colorFore=FFFFFFFF colorBack=null
>
> Cell=BBH57 Grey 4 indexFore=0 indexBack=64 colorFore=FFFFFFFF colorBack=null
>
> Cell=BBH58 Grey 5 indexFore=0 indexBack=64 colorFore=FFFFFFFF colorBack=null
>
> Cell=BBH59 White indexFore=0 indexBack=64 colorFore=FFFFFFFF colorBack=null

Any idea why the shades of Grey and White all translate to a Hex value of FFFFFFFF?  Is there a more correct method to access the actual fill color?  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Excel 2013 workbook" is a workbook stored in `Office Open XML` format. There the colors may have an extra 4th alpha channel but also may have  [ColorType.Tint property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.colortype.tint.aspx)  set. So actually all grey shades are `RGB` white `FFFFFF` having different `tint` set. For example in `xl/styles.xml` the `Grey 1` is:

```
...
<fill>
 <patternFill patternType="solid">
  <fgColor theme="0" tint="-0.0499893185216834"/>
  <bgColor indexed="64"/>
 </patternFill>
</fill>
...
```

Theme color 0 is white `FFFFFF` and the `tint` `-0.0499893185216834` is darkening that white to grey.

So we must take the `tint` into account. Fortunaltely `apache poi`'s  [ExtendedColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ExtendedColor.html) provides method [getRGBWithTint](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/ExtendedColor.html#getRGBWithTint--) for this.

So the following example gets the fill colors properly also if they have `tint` set:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

public class ReadExcelColorHavingTint {

 private static String getFillColorHex(Cell cell) throws Exception { 
  String fillColorString = "none";
  if (cell != null) {
   CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
   Color color =  cellStyle.getFillForegroundColorColor();
   if (color instanceof XSSFColor) {
    XSSFColor xssfColor = (XSSFColor)color;
    byte[] argb = xssfColor.getARGB();
    fillColorString = "[" + (argb[0]&0xFF) + ", " + (argb[1]&0xFF) + ", " + (argb[2]&0xFF) + ", " + (argb[3]&0xFF) + "]";
    if (xssfColor.hasTint()) {
     fillColorString += " * " + xssfColor.getTint();
     byte[] rgb = xssfColor.getRGBWithTint();
     fillColorString += " = [" + (argb[0]&0xFF) + ", " + (rgb[0]&0xFF) + ", " + (rgb[1]&0xFF) + ", " + (rgb[2]&0xFF) + "]" ;
    }
   } else if (color instanceof HSSFColor) {
    HSSFColor hssfColor = (HSSFColor)color;
    short[] rgb = hssfColor.getTriplet();
    fillColorString = "[" + rgb[0] + ", " + rgb[1] + ", "  + rgb[2] + "]";
   }
  }
  return fillColorString;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx"));
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("workbook.xls"));
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {

    System.out.println("Cell=" + cell.getAddress() + " " + cell.toString() + " " + getFillColorHex(cell));

   }
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: Perfect answer - thanks.  I learned something and the new code now gives the right answer for all my test cases.